# JSON with empty numeral value? (not 0)

Tags: javascript, json

**Given a JSON such:**

```
[
{ "id":"A", "status": 1, "rank":1, "score":  },
{ "id":"B", "status": 1, "rank":1, "score":  }
]
```

My script fails due to the empty score.

**Given a JS such :**

```
if (json[i].score) { do something } else { calculate it }
```

I want to keep the field **empty**, and not use 0. I may use `"score": ""`, but this will imply that it's a string (empty at start), while I want score to be **a numeral** (empty at start). So the number I push in it stay a number, and not a string.

**How to state an empty/undefined numeral ?**

---

Note: I intuitively think it's why I sometime meet `undefined`.

---

**EDIT:** the question was edited to clarify the context, the need to check the existence of obj.score, where 0 would be misleading.

Comment: How about `null`?

Comment: Don't know. I'am the newbee

Comment: you could try something like parseInt(''), but get you somewhere but I think if it's a numeric value it's going to want something in there, even if it's just a 0 (although I'll admit I've never had to look into that for anything).

Comment: i agree with @elclanrs.  `null` is a valid value here and has a clearer meaning than a 0.

Comment: Either use null or leave it out.

Comment: What if I test the existence of `"score": null` ? Return true or false (non existing)

Comment: Test like: `if (obj.score != null) // checks null & undefined`

Comment: @elclanrs: Douglas Crowford would scream at you for using "`!=`" (http://www.jslint.com/) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Use `0` (zero), if everyone starts with zero score. Use `null`, if you specifically want to say that someone's score is not set yet. Do not define the property, if it should not be placed in specific case (like object that should not even have `"score"` property).

### Omitting the value in JSON object

Well, in JSON you are not allowed to just omit the value. It must be set to something like number (integer or float), object, list, boolean, null or string. To read more about syntax, try this resource: http://json.org/. This is the diagram taken from that site, showing you the syntax of object representations in JSON:

[image]

### Most popular approaches: `null`, `0` (zero), undefined

The usual approach is to set `null`. In other cases it can be better to use `0` (zero), if applicable (eg. the field means "*sum*").

Another approach is just to not set the property. After deserialization you are then able to perform tests checking the existence of specific property like that:

- JavaScript:

  ```js
  if (typeof my_object.score !== 'undefined'){
      // "score" key exists in the object
  }
  ```
- Python:

  ```py
  if 'score' in my_object:
      pass  # "score" key exists in the object
  ```
- PHP:

  ```php
  if (array_key_exists('score', $my_object)) {
      // "score" key exists in the object
  }
  ```

### Less consistent approaches: `false`, `""`

Some people also accept the value to be `false` in such case, but it is rather inconsistent. Similarly when it comes to empty string (`""`). However, both cases should be properly supported in most programming languages during deserialization.

Comment: Note: `0` is not `undefined`. Is `null` a synonym of `0` or of `undefined` ?

Comment: @Hugolpz: The example code I have given demonstrates how to detect that specific property was not even present in the JSON representation. `null` could be a synonym of `0` or `undefined`, but only in very specific cases. In general it has slightly different semantics. `null` means something like "there is a property, but it is >empty<", `0` means "the property is set, but is currently equal to zero", while `undefined` means "the property was not set".

Answer (score 1):

Why not just start score at 0? Everyone will start with a score of 0 in just about anything involving score.

```
[
  { "id":"A", "status": 1, "rank":1, "score": 0 },
  { "id":"B", "status": 1, "rank":1, "score": 0 }
]
```

Comment: Because I currently use `if (json[i].score) { do nothing } else { calculate it }`. So i need an empty numeral. I'am curious if I can do something such `"score":""`, but I may finally end up with `if (json[i].score) { do nothing } else (json[i].score = 0) { calculate it }`

Comment: If all you have to do is change your conditional statement, i don't see why you wouldnt, since you can't have an uninitialized value in JSON (it will ALWAYS have something stored, never nothing)

Comment: Here, it's basic curiosity.

Comment: Taylor: thanks for the tips of 'always having something', sound better indeed.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a numeral value is a *value type*, which cannot be `null`. Only *reference types* (like strings, arrays, etc.) should be initialized to `null`.

For the semantic of your situation, I would suggest you to use a boolean to know if weither or not there is a score to be read.

```
[
    { "id":"A", "status": 1, "rank":1, "empty":true  },
    { "id":"B", "status": 1, "rank":1, "empty":false, "score":100}
]
```

Then,

```
if (!foo.empty) {
    var score = foo.score;
}
```

While a `null` could be tested as well, it is a wrong representation of a number.